# Is a Jersey Client WebTarget thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, jackson, jersey, jersey-2.0

Is a Jersey Client `WebTarget` created as following thread-safe?

```
WebTarget client = ClientBuilder
        .newClient(new ClientConfig(new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider(<object mapper Jackson>, JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.DEFAULT_ANNOTATIONS)))
        .target("<url>");
```

Note that the Jackson `ObjectMapper` must also be thread-safe for this.

Comment: Related question: [Is java Jersey 2.1 client thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18078666).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The methods on a WebTarget that create request builders or new WebTargets are thread safe. The methods inherited from Configurable, that modify the ClientConfig may not be thread safe.

Jackson ObjectMapper is also thread safe.

So as long as you don't reconfigure the WebTarget after initialisation you should be good to go.

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Comment: any source for this ?

Comment: Source for which part of my answer? The mentioned WebTarget methods don't mutate the object on which they are called, they create new objects. Hence, they are thread safe. Thread safety of ObjectMapper (except for reconfiguring) is specified, see e.g. https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html

Comment: Ok, but I was hoping for some mention in Jersey 2.x doc, like it was mentionned in Jersey 1.x doc : http://javadox.com/com.sun.jersey/jersey-client/1.19/com/sun/jersey/api/client/Client.html